# Identify record type associated to a web to lead form

Tags: record-type, web2lead

I don't find the record type in the "view page source" code of the website for which we have an existing web to lead form.

Is there any way to identify how a website is associated with a lead record type.

Answer (score 2):

The record type will be determined by by one of the following:

- The Record Type in the Web-to-Lead form.
- The Default Record Type for the new Lead Owner, if assigned to a user by assignment rule.
- The Default Record Type for the Queue's Owner, if assigned to a queue by assignment rule.
- The Default Record Type for the Default Lead Creator, if nothing else applies.
- Any triggers, workflows, or process builders that may have been configured.

Since there's multiple places to set the Record Type, there's no one place you can go to determine what the Record Type will end up being. You'll have to look at the total system configuration if you're not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we write when we generate code in salesforce:

```
<input type=hidden name="recordType" id="recordType" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"> //where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is recordtypeid
```

which is then further added to the website's form. I just checked, that page source shows the same line as I have written above.

Please check following salesforce documention:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005177&type=1

Let me know this helps!

Comment: i couldnt find anything by the name "recordType" in my page source.

Comment: @Sowparnika are you able to find anything with tag <input type=hidden> ???

Comment: I just Updated answer,why its down voted

Comment: @AnnappaPH, the ask of this question is not what you answered!

Comment: Have you checked the link.what I had given.Its already available same thing you posted here.I have provided few steps and check my first link whats the wrong in that

Comment: @AnnappaPH, the question asks for how to find the record type through website, that is through page source. Also, no one said, the question is closed, you are obviously free to answer. I just mentioned the possible reason, why the answer could have been downvoted.

Comment: Also, @Sowparnika, through the form, why don't you create a test record and check Salesforce, as of for what record type the record is getting created and then search the form for the same record type's id. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: yes.but question is still open right. i had provide the few steps.only one step i have added extra(keep the existing record type)..then I have posted the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79226/discussion-between-annappa-ph-and-khushboo-dua).

Comment: @Sowparnika where are we on this? Are we resolved with the issue? Please let us know!